# Cacti reports kilorows as a Mysql Sort

Tags: mysql, cacti

In my cacti installation, the graph that reports on mysql sorts has a value kiloRows.  What does this value mean?  I can't seem to find anything on it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the source code, turns out cacti is taking the mysql SORT_ROWS variables, and dividing by 1024.