# Mysql Daily Performance Reporting

Tags: mysql, performance, reporting

I wish to create a daily report on how my mysql server perform on the day. But it seems like mysql only stores aggregate data since uptime.
One way is to generate a report and then do a mysql restart (or do a FLUSH STATUS).

Any other suggestions to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [MySQL Cacti Templates](http://code.google.com/p/mysql-cacti-templates/). They provide a large number of graphs that display your MySQL server performance over time. Here is a [demo page](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2008/05/25/screenshots-of-improved-mysql-cacti-templates/).

Answer (score 0):

Cacti is pretty awesome.  It also helps you determine performance over time as you make changes to your code base.

Also, some of the values it reports on are pretty cryptic. Here's [an answer that explains kilorows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840212/cacti-reports-kilorows-as-a-mysql-sort/840955#840955).

Answer (score 0):

I agree that Cacti is awesome but I preferred using Munin since I found it easier to create new templates in Munin.